# Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

In very rare scenarios I get error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'. And I'm not sure how to deal/fix this. It occurs randomly, not on same row. When I try something to write, make borders and other stuff I always cast ((MyExcel.Range)Excel.Cells..).Value = .., sometimes its just a string, numbers, arrays, borders, or trying insert new rows. The Code below it's just a sample.

```
using MyExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...

private void xx()
try
{
    MyExcel.Application Excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    ((MyExcel.Range)Excel.Cells[5, 5]).Value = aaa1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to break the chain of property and method calls:

```
((MyExcel.Range)Excel.Cells[5, 5]).Value = aaa1;
```

First, declare the range object in the following way:

```
MyExcel.Range range = Excel.Cells[5, 5] as MyExcel.Range;
```

Now if the `range` object is not `null` you can try to call the `Value` property.

Comment: Ty for answer. Few questions to clarify: 
1. If my range is on variable eg "Cells[i, y]", so I will need to check every cell or range is not null ?
2. If my range = null, it means error happend?
3. You are saying problem here lies in chain properties and method calls in single row? Some kind memory bug?

BTW I'm using .NET Framework 3.5